# Video editing displays white screen

Tags: video

I have Blender 2.72b on Windows 8.1 Pro and whenever I get to the video editing and import a video, I get this

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you upload one of your videos or just a part of it?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I've tested .mp4 (h264), .mov (h264) and .avi (uncompressed) clips in windows 8.1 and it works as expected. I assume it's a graphic card issue, like here: https://developer.blender.org/T37904. Do you have installed latest drivers?

Comment: I have the latest drivers (ATI Radeon 3100 Graphics).

Comment: Then there must be a codec issue. Which video formats you've tested? Can you upload a part (1-3 seconds) of one .mp4 that displays white?

Answer (score 1):

I already had a graphics card driver problem with Blender. The developers helped me [out](https://developer.blender.org/T45270#319163) to find out whether the problem is one with the driver.

You should use the *opengl32.dll* from http://download.blender.org/ftp/sergey/softwaregl/ and place it next to your *blender.exe* as described by sergey to find out if the problem is your driver. Beware, that Blender might be very slow while using this wrapper dll as everything is done on CPU only without using your graphics card. If it's working this way you know it's a problem with your driver/graphics card.